# PyO3 - How to return enums to python module?

Tags: python, rust, enums, pyo3

I'm trying to build a Python package from Rust using PyO3. Right now I'm stuck trying to return `enums` Rust type to Python.

I have a simple enum like so:

```rust
pub enum Lang {
    Deu,
    Eng,
    Fra
}
```

And in `lib.rs`

```rust
#[pyfunction]
fn detect_language(text: &str) -> PyResult<????> {
   // Do some stuff ....
   res:Lang = Do_some_stuff(text)
   Ok(res)
}

#[pymodule]
fn pymylib(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(detect_language, m)?)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

In Python code

```py
from pymylib import detect_language

res=detect_language('Ceci est un test')
print(res) # Lang:Fra ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would to use `#[pyclass]` attribute to make the Python class from Rust Enum. Also make sure to export this class from Rust code, so that you can do the comparison on python layer.
ie,

```
use pyo3::prelude::*;

#[pyclass]
pub enum Lang {
    Deu,
    Eng,
    Fra
}

#[pyfunction]
fn detect_language(text: &str) -> PyResult<Lang> {
    // Write your actual code here
    // But for testing purpose let's return `Deu` varient.
    Ok(Lang::Deu)
}

/// A Python module implemented in Rust.
#[pymodule]
fn pymylib(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(detect_language, m)?)?;
    m.add_class::<Lang>()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Now in Python interpreter you can do,

```
>>> from pymylib import Lang
>>> import pymylib
>>> 
>>> pymylib.detect_language("1")
Lang.Deu
>>> pymylib.detect_language("1") == Lang.Deu
True
```

See also

- [Support exporting Rust enums to Python](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/issues/417)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

But if I have a variable of type `enum` defined in another crate, how can use #[pyclass] attribute to make the Python class from this variable?

eg: ```
use cratelang;

#[pyclass]
type Lang = cratelang::Lang; // Got ERROR
```

Answer (score 1):

In combination with the fact that python's naming guidelines for enum variants are different to rust's, I generally turn the rust enum into a string in the pyo3 interface, and then wrap it in a [StrEnum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.StrEnum) on the python side. This doesn't require too much extra code:

```rust
// interface.rs

#[pyfunction]
fn detect_language(text: &str) -> PyResult<&'static str> {
    Ok(match actual_detect_language(text) {
        Lang::Deu => "deu",
        Lang::Eng => "eng",
        Lang::Fra => "fra",
    })
}
```

```py
# interface.py
from enum import StrEnum

import pymylib

class Languge(StrEnum):
    DEU = "deu"
    ENG = "eng"
    FRA = "fra"

def detect_language(text: str) -> Language:
    return Language(pymylib.detect_language(text))
```

You can do the same thing in reverse if you need the enum back on the rust side: StrEnum inherits from str and so can be passed straight into any pyo3 function which takes a str. You can just panic on the "other" variant in the match on the rust side because using the StrEnum guarantees the variant exists.

Comment: `StrEnum` is only in Python V 3.11

Comment: Indeed, this is a forward-facing answer. There is a backport package available for python 3.8+, and the implementation is pretty simple otherwise.